# Sonata-NewsBundle does not install on Symfony 3.2.9

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I use Symfony 3.2.9 and I try install Sontata News Bundle 3.0.0 . The bundle doesnt install . Is there a solution for Symfony 3.2.* yet?

My requirement (composer.json):

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=7.0",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
  "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
  "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
  "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
  "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
  "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
  "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.20",
  "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.3",
  "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "^2.3",
  "sonata-project/dashboard-bundle": "^0.1.0",
  "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
  "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.2",
  "sonata-project/news-bundle": "^3.1",
  "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^3.1",
  "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
  "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
  "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
  "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
  "symfony/translation": "^3.2",
  "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.2-dev"
    }
}
```

Anwser of the console:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of     packages.
Problem 1
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle    ^2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.3.0, v2.x.x ...].
```

- symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9 requires symfony/translation ~2.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.x.x, ...] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Should I install a version of old symfony?**